# Inserting only few columns into cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am new to cassandra, is it possible to insert into only few columns in a table and leaving other columns for future filling?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The syntax of the [CQL INSERT](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/insert_r.html) gives you what you'd expect:

`INSERT INTO table (col_1, col_5) VALUES (val1, val5)`

Comment: Do I need to use again insert or update for future filling of all other remaining columns?

Comment: You can use either. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532227/difference-between-update-and-insert-in-cassandra, http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_inserts_c.html, http://planetcassandra.org/blog/how-to-do-an-upsert-in-cassandra/ for more details.